# Is there a way to align nav and main so that main fills the empty space page?

Tags: html, css

I'm brand new to this so please excuse me if I'm way off track.

I'm just playing around with a website that is centered on a page. What I want to is for  to fill the gap that's under  but I can't seem to figure out how to do it, or if it's even possible. I might be doing a poor job of explaining what I want to do so I'll include a picture of what it looks like now and what I actually would like it to look like to make it easier to understand.

[What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZOZo.png)

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwo5O.png)

What can I do with my code to do this? Is it even possible?

```css
html {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 960px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}

#box1 {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box2 {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box4 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

main {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div id="box1">
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're structuring `<main>` outside of `<nav>` it is sitting on the right hand side, you can add `position` css attribute to nav and it will sit on top of the main, if this is something that you're after, is there something specific you want to site underneath the nav?

https://jsfiddle.net/bz1wa0my/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/

Comment: I ended up using "position: absolute;" and that seems to do what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your div elements inside of main tag like this

```css
html {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

nav {
    background-color: black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: purple;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}

main {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
<nav>
    <div id="box1">
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
    </div>
    <div id="box3">
    </div>
    <div id="box4">
    </div>
</nav>

</main>
```

Comment: You need to set `min-height: 100vh;` (instead of `height: 100vh`) on `main` or you will see truncation of the `background` when scrolling becomes necessary.

Comment: Ok. Would it be good form to do this even if the <nav> is designed to be site-wide (not just used on that particular page)?